# How do matrix solutions represent an intersection of lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm very new to linear algebra, and I have a homework problem that hasn't been covered in the book or by the professor. It seems like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what matrices represent, but I can't find a good article or answer.

> Do the three lines $x_1 - 4x_2 = 1$, $2x_1 - x_2 = -3$, and $-x_1 - 3x_2 = 4$ have a common point of intersection? Explain.

I assumed that the solution set of the matrix would represent how many intersections there were. I solved the echelon form and got:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 & & 1\\2& -1 & & -3\\-1 & -3 & & 4\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 & & 1\\0& 1 & & -\frac{5}{7}\\0 & 0 & & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Since this has infinite solutions, I would have thought it meant there were infinite intersections, or rather two equivalent lines, but that obviously isn't true. Is there any relationship between the solution set of a matrix and its original equations/lines? What is the matrix actually representing?

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce it further.  When you do, the first row is $(1,0,-13/7)$ which says that your simultaneous solution is $(-13/7, -5/7)$.  So, there is one point of intersection.

Since you have only two variables but three equations, you would need an extra 0-row in order to get infinitely many solutions, and this would imply that two of your lines were the same to begin with.

You may have temporarily forgotten that your matrix was augmented?  It's not really "square."

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct (I assume you have row-reduced properly) but the bottom row gives you no information - does $0x + 0y + 0z = 0$ tell you anything about $x, y,$ or $z$? You can safely scrub out a row of zeroes from a matrix and solve the system from there.

Answer (score 0):

If your augmented matrix is of the form $[A | C]$ then system has unique solution if $rank(A)=rank(C)$=number of unknowns.
Here, $ank(A)=rank(C)=$number of unknowns=2 
So, unique soon i.e a single intersection point